Evaluating a plus symbol from parsed text as a ggplot2 operator
Questions like this one explain how to evaluate a parsed string, but this doesn't seem to work when a + is inside the string as an operator for combining layers of a ggplot.
E.g.
ggplot(data = mtcars) + eval(parse(text = "geom_point(aes(x = cyl, y = disp))"))

works, but this doesn't:
ggplot(data = mtcars) + 
  eval(parse(text = "geom_point(aes(x = cyl, y = disp)) + theme_bw()"))

Is there another way to evaluate the + operator in the ggplot context?

Using the combination eval(parse(…)) is almost never a good idea (as you can see here). Please describe what problem you’re trying to solve, so that users can suggest more appropriate solutions.

This happens because of the order of operations. When you call eval() on that string, the geom_point() and theme_bw() are added first, which is not valid ggplot2 code. If you want to go down this path, you would need to ensure that first + addition is the one following ggplot(). (I completely agree with Konrad though.) Note that you can combine elements in a list first, as in l <- list(geom_point(aes(cyl, disp)), theme_bw()), then add them to a ggplot object like ggplot(mtcars) + l

The string will vary and is passed to a function; the + theme_bw() might be just one of several + layers a user want to add, so it can't be fixed.  However, your list option solved my issue.  Thanks. Please include as an answer :)

The + in ggplot2 is a +.gg method.  That is it acts on a gg class object on the left hand side (LHS).  ggplot(...)  is a gg class object and so is ggplot(...) + geom_point() but geom_point(...) is not a gg class object so geom_point(...) + theme_bw() is invalid.

Following @Axeman's insight, here's a way to do what you want:
p <- ggplot(data = mtcars)
eval(parse(text = "p + geom_point(aes(x = cyl, y = disp)) + theme_bw()"))

The reason this works is that R uses the class of the first object in a sum to dispatch to the right method to handle it.  In your original example that failed, the first object was geom_point(aes(x = cyl, y = disp)) with a different class than ggplot(data = mtcars) has.

Thanks for this alternative solution.  This also works, and is aesthetically more pleasing IMO (despite the eval(parse(…))  cautions of usage) given that this is to be a user defined string which will be dynamic.  Easier to simply add quotes than replace + with , and put inside a list.
